# MappingProvider's errorMapping always fails with: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit

I am experiencing difficulties mapping my API's errors. I am loading requests using blocks like this:

```
[self.objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:resourcePath usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects) {
        // ...
    };
    loader.onDidFailLoadWithError = ^(NSError *error) {
        // ...
    };
    loader.onDidFailWithError = ^(NSError *error) {
        // ...
    };
}];
```

On the server side if, eg, I attempt to authenticate a user with wrong username/password, my API returns and error with the following format:

```
{ "error":
    {"code":"401",
    "message":"Wrong username etc. etc."}
}
```

In the [object mapping docs](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping) I have found the following:

> #### RKErrorMessage
>
> A simple class providing for the mapping of server-side error messages
> back to NSError objects [...] When an RKObjectManager is initialized,
> object mappings from the "error" and "errors" keyPaths to instances of
> RKErrorMessage are registered with the mapping provider. This provides
> out of the box mapping support for simple error messages. [...]

Which I interpret as the object loader automatically will map any "error" og "errors" keyPath's accordingly, and didFailWithError: (or block) will get called. This is not the situation, though. I get this error every time an error response is loaded from the API:

> Adding mapping error: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''

I have tried solutions from [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851239/how-do-i-setup-restkit-0-10-0-to-recognize-error-and-errors-messages) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841203/restkit-json-error-response-msg-from-server), but the result is the same.

I know the json is loaded from my API, I have tracked that in the debugger. Also, if I create an RKObjectMapping and maps it to the "error" keyPath, onDidLoadObjects block is fired with an Error object, but this is not what I intend to do.

Long story short, my goal is that make RestKit fire an onDidFailWithError block whenever an "error" keyPath is returned by my API.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I would assume the problem to be with your server the error response with a 2xx status code.

Other possibilities are either using a version of RK predating the docs you mention, or you might have found a bug :)